# A Python function to calculate correlation matrix using the arbitrary number of variables

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

Is there a function in Python that calculates a (Pearson) correlation matrix using an arbitrary number of Numpy arrays, while deals with NaNs in those arrays at the same time?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
a = np.random.random(10)
b = np.random.random(10)
c = np.random.random(10)
a[np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)] = np.nan
b[np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)] = np.nan
c[np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)] = np.nan
ma.corrcoef(ma.masked_invalid(a), ma.masked_invalid(b))
```

The ma.corrcoef() is close to what I am looking for, but it only takes two arrays; The result of `ma.corrcoef(ma.masked_invalid(a), ma.masked_invalid(b))` is the same with `ma.corrcoef(ma.masked_invalid(a), ma.masked_invalid(b), , ma.masked_invalid(c))`. And I want to pass many arrays and create the correlation matrix. For example, a_ideal_function(array1, array2, array3, array4, ..., arrayN) will create a correlation matrix with the size of NxN.

Additionally...

- My arrays will be of 1-D.
- I know that `pandas.DataFrame().corr()` will do it, but I want to do it using `numpy.Array()`, for running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to pass the three 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray' elements inside [ ], this will output a 3x3 correlation matrix as expected.

Concretely, this code.

`ma.corrcoef([ma.masked_invalid(a), ma.masked_invalid(b),ma.masked_invalid(c)])`

Comment: Thank you. I have a problem with making a function based on your suggestion; I will ask via another question.